# Textbox with reference to dropdown returns nothing

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have `cmbCountry` on a form as an unbound dropdown. The dropdown works as expected. I have setup a textbox called `txtCM_ID` on the same form, in which I want to display the ID that was selected in the dropdown.

When I enter the record source for the textbox as `=Forms![frm_ClientModel]!cmbCountry.Column(0)` access automatically changes it to read `=[Forms]![frm_ClientModel]![cmbCountry].[column](0)`

My version returns the correct information when i test it in the VBE Immediate window. The code that access produces returns the below when run in the Immediate window:

> runtime error 450: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property
>   assignment

The frustrating thing is, that regardless of where or how i enter the code in the control source, access changes it to its version. When the form is opened the `txtCM_ID` simply remains blank.

I have also tried to go around this problem by changing my reference to the following: `Forms("frm_ClientModel").Controls("cmbCountry").column(0)`

While this version (also tested and ok in VBE) doesn't produce an error, it too returns nothing in the text box.

What am I missing / doing wrong / overlooking?

Comment: `txtCM_ID=me.controls("cmbCountry").value`

Comment: Access changes that to =[me].[controls]("cmbCountry").[Value]

Comment: Are you doing this by code, or in the form properties?  If doing in form, may be best to take off the VBA tag

Comment: I'm doing it in the form. I was testing in the VBE in order to verify that it actually (should) work

Comment: I removed the VBA tag

Comment: I ended up solving it by creating a OnClick Event which then wrote to the Text Field via Code. Interestingly enough, I had to to use the following code Forms("frm_ClientModel").Controls("cmbCountry").column(0) otherwise all I got from the dropdown was the position of the record I selected in the dropdown.

Comment: I've just tested, using a combo and setting to the combo name, gave me column 0 value, changing bound column gave me different column values.

Answer (score 1):

Use just

```
=[cmbCountry]
```

To access the value of cmbCountry from other control.

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't give me any result. Remains blank.

Comment: The exact same setup works perfectly on another form. Something about my form might be interfering?

Comment: Try to check the name carefully, try to rename the source control, it should work

Comment: I have renamed the dropdown and tried it but nothing. I deleted and created a new textbox. Same thing. I will now make a copy of the form and go through and delete other controls out of it item for item.

Comment: Having done the above, I am now getting results, but only after deleting the main forms query!

Comment: This wasn't the answer, but under normal circustances your suggestion does work. +1 for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to specifically determine why this happened, but ended up solving the issue by using the OnClick Event of the Dropdown and writing the needed info into the Textbox via VBA with this:

```
Private Sub cmbCountry_AfterUpdate()
    Me.txt_CMID = Forms("frm_ClientModel").Controls("cmbCountry").Column(0)
End Sub
```

If anyone else finds an answer as to why form controls did not work properly I would be interested in hearing from you.